# select query with join is selecting data slowly from database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have select query as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.firstname, 
                tt.lastname, 
                tc.caseid, 
                tt.courtcode                AS courtid, 
                tcou.courtname, 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                 FROM   tblcasetrafficticketlink 
                 WHERE  caseid = tc.caseid) AS ticketcount, 
                Max(tt.violationdate)       AS violationdate, 
                ( tt.address1 
                   || ',' 
                   || tt.address2 )         AS address, 
                tt.city, 
                tt.state, 
                tt.zip, 
                tt.dob, 
                tt.sex 
FROM   tblcase tc 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcasetrafficticketlink tcttl 
         ON tc.caseid = tcttl.caseid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbltraffictickets tt 
         ON tcttl.courtid = tt.courtcode 
            AND tt.ticketnumber = tcttl.ticketnumber 
            AND ( tcttl.ticketextension = tt.ticketnumberex 
                   OR tt.ticketnumberex IS NULL ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcourts tcou 
         ON tcou.courtid = tt.courtcode 
WHERE  tc.casetype = 'TRAFFIC' 
       AND tc.caseid<='"+recent_min_caseID+"' 
GROUP  BY tc.caseid, 
          tt.firstname, 
          tt.lastname, 
          tt.dob, 
          tt.sex, 
          tt.courtcode, 
          tcou.courtname, 
          tt.city, 
          tt.state, 
          tt.zip, 
          tc.casestatus, 
          tt.address1, 
          tt.address2 
ORDER  BY tc.caseid DESC 
LIMIT  100;
```

this is taking much time to get data. can anybody help to improve performance.Here PRAGMA is useful? if so how? if not, tell me the way to fix this issue.

Comment: Time is depend on How much data you are fetch from db, you can set progress dialog when data is loaded from db..

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr.Hasmukh ,totally to select the records it is taking 4-5 seconds i want to reduce that time

Comment: I have 3 tables each table has nearly 4000 records and 15 columns how to join these tables and i want to get fast response in retrieving data from database.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that SQLite on Android seems to have some... unexpected quirks. In my case, it turned out that doing a straight query like `select * from Foo where Bar is null` was MUCH slower than selecting *only* the IDs and then fetching each row by ID individually. YMMV.